# How to correctly specify colname for tables?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, html-table

My source xml looks like:

```
<TABLE>
  <ROW>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="3"> Test </CELL>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="2"> Test </CELL>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="1"> Test </CELL>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="3"> Test </CELL>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="1"> Test </CELL>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="1"> Test </CELL>
    <CELL ROWSPAN="1"> Test </CELL>
  </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

The correct transformed output should look like:

```
<tbody>
  <row>
    <entry colname="1"> Test </entry>
    <entry colname="2"> Test </entry>
    <entry colname="3"> Test </entry>
    <entry colname="4"> Test </entry>
    <entry colname="5"> Test </entry>
 </row>
 <row>
   <entry colname="3"> Test </entry>
   <entry colname="5"> Test </entry>
 </row>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, the tricky part is the second row element. Since the first row has several cells occupying multiple rows, thus it will affect the colnames of the second row, that is why the first entry of the second row starts with colname "3" instead of "1". I don't know how to draw a table here, but if you depict it on a paper, you will easily understand.

Currently, I have the following xsl that could partially capture this(I omitted other info since I only have problems with @colname)

```
<xsl:template match="CELL">
   <xsl:if test="../preceding-sibling::ROW[1]/CELL[1]/@ROWSPAN > 1">
     <xsl:attribute name="colname" select="position()+count(../preceding-sibling::ROW[1]/CELL[@ROWSPAN>1])"/>
    ..
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will not work great since it will include all the CELLs that have a mutiple row span into its count, thus the result will look like:

```
  <row>
    <entry colname="4"> Test </entry>
    <entry colname="5"> Test </entry>
  </row>
```

While the first entry should really start at 3.

I found it is a bit hard to describe this problem, but I will try my best, if further info, is needed, please leave a comment below.

Comment: I have never used `rowspan` and don't know what it is supposed to mean. XSLT and XPath experts aren't supposed to know any particular XML vocabulary, even if it happens to be XHTML.  Please, edit the question with a definition of the meaning of `rowspan`.

Comment: This looks VERY tricky to do, considering the output could potentially depend on any number of previous `ROW` elements. I've got an idea floating around my head about using a recursive template that processes each row in turn passing in a list of 'occupied' rows from previous rows, but it's going to take some time to flesh out.

Comment: Quick question: Are you like to be using the `COLSPAN` tag as well? If so, that significantly complicates things.

Comment: @Flynn1179 The COLSPAN is not used, I used namest and namend instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution's quite complicated, and I've got a nagging feeling there might be a better way of doing it, but it seems to work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="TABLE">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[1]" />
    </tbody>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <xsl:param name="occupiedcols" />
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CELL[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="occupiedcols" select="$occupiedcols" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </row>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ROW[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="occupiedcols">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CELL[1]" mode="getoccupied">
          <xsl:with-param name="occupiedcols" select="$occupiedcols" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CELL">
    <xsl:param name="occupiedcols" />
    <xsl:param name="col" select="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="thiscol" select="$col + string-length(substring-before(substring($occupiedcols,$col,255),'0'))" />
    <xsl:element name="entry">
      <xsl:attribute name="colname">
        <xsl:value-of select="$thiscol" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::CELL[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="occupiedcols" select="$occupiedcols"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$thiscol + 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CELL" mode="getoccupied">
    <xsl:param name="occupiedcols" />
    <xsl:param name="col" select="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="thiscol" select="$col + string-length(substring-before(substring($occupiedcols,$col,255),'0'))" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(substring($occupiedcols,$col,255),'0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(substring($occupiedcols,$col,255),'0'),'0123456789','-012345678')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($occupiedcols,$col,255),'123456789','012345678')" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="@ROWSPAN - 1" />
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::CELL)">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($occupiedcols,$thiscol + 1, 255),'0123456789','0012345678')" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::CELL[1]" mode="getoccupied">
      <xsl:with-param name="occupiedcols" select="$occupiedcols"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$thiscol + 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's one known issue with it: It will break if a cell spans more than 9 rows. It's actually quite easy to adapt if that's a problem.

Also, it doesn't support any use of `COLSPAN`.

It works by passing a string of digits detailing the number of rows that still have a cell for each column, so the second row would get passed '21020' in your example, and it calculates the `colname` attribute based on where the 0's are. A second pass through each row reduces the digits by one, but subsituting 0's for the `ROWSPAN` for each cell.

This solution also assumes that ALL cells have a `ROWSPAN` attribute even if they only span one. If that's not the case, I can add in a means of supporting the default of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good idea would be to maintain a bit vector that for each column contains the number of rows the previous cell in this column will expand to. To do that, you have to use recursion, as you have to modify the bit vector for each row and XSLT as functional programming language has no means of modifying "variables".

The following stylesheet shows the idea for a table with 3 columns.

```
<xsl:template match="TABLE2">
  <tbody>
    <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
      <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="ROW"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="processRows">
  <xsl:param name="rows"/>
  <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
  <!-- Bit vector for the columns -->
  <xsl:param name="col1" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="col2" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="col3" select="0"/>

  <xsl:variable name="cellsBefore2">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$col1 > 0">0</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="cellsBefore3">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$col2 > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$cellsBefore2"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$cellsBefore2 + 1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <row>
    <xsl:if test="$col1 = 0">
      <entry colname="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rows[$index]/CELL[1]/text()"/>
      </entry>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$col2 = 0">
      <entry colname="2">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rows[$index]/CELL[$cellsBefore2 + 1]/text()"/>
      </entry>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$col3 = 0">
      <entry colname="3">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rows[$index]/CELL[$cellsBefore3 + 1]/text()"/>
      </entry>
    </xsl:if>
  </row>
  <xsl:if test="$index &lt; count($rows)">
    <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
      <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$rows"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col1">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$col1 > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$col1 - 1"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="number($rows[$index]/CELL[1]/@ROWSPAN) - 1"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="col2">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$col2 > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$col2 - 1"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="number($rows[$index]/CELL[$cellsBefore2 + 1]/@ROWSPAN) - 1"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="col3">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$col3 > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$col3 - 1"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="number($rows[$index]/CELL[$cellsBefore3 + 1]/@ROWSPAN) - 1"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As you see, the problem is that the number of columns is hardcoded. If you want to have an arbitrary number of columns, you need to be able to generate and pass a list of arbitrary length as parameter. This is possible only in XSLT 2.0. However, if you're on XSLT 1.1, you can instead use EXSLT (if it's available in your environment), write the list as result tree in a variable and use exslt:node-set() on this variable to get a usable list.

Comment: thank you! This is of tremendous help. Could you please show me how to do pass the list of arbitrary length as parameter please?

Comment: I guess it's easier to go with the other solution, it solves the problem by concatenating the vector into a string.